# Displaying multiple objects in a DetailView

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have been dabbling with Django CBV lately and have a question. Maybe you have better ideas than I.

Assume I have a airline booking CRM application and I intend to perform a display of a customer for various things. Assume I have a list of `Models`, for a `Customer` like `Booking`, `Rating`, `Customer_Service_Calls`, `Favourited_Route`.

Now, given a `DetailView` implemented by Django's CBV, I have something like this

```
class CustomerThreeSixtyView(DetailView):
  model = 'Customer'

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      context = super(CustomerThreeSixtyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
      context['bookings'] = Booking.objects.all.filter(customer_id=request.kwargs['pk']
      context['ratings'] = Ratings.objects.all.filter(customer_id=request.kwargs['pk']
      context['calls'] = Customer_Service_Calls.objects.all.filter(customer_id=request.kwargs['pk'], status'Open')
      context['fav_routes'] = Favourited_Route.objects.all.filter(customer_id=request.kwargs['pk'], status'Open')
      return context
```

Something like this. My question is that, are there better ways to do this? This is the most straightforward way but I'm asking for suggestions because there seem to be bound for something.

Comment: As an aside, you can set `context_object_name = 'customer'` on your view class and then reference it that way in the template. Helpful if you don't want to refer to your `Customer` object as `object` all the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have done already looks good enough. You are getting what you required in the context and then using it in the template to show the information.

Alternatively, you could directly access bookings for a particular customer in the template without specifying it in the context:

```
{% for booking in object.booking_set.all %} # object is the customer here
     # do what you want to do with the booking here
{% endfor %}
```

It is even better if you use [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) while linking the customer to Booking:

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name='bookings')
    # other fields
```

Now, you can directly use the defined `related_name` to access the bookings for a particular customer:

```
{% for booking in object.bookings.all %}
     # do what you want to do with the booking here
{% endfor %}
```

And, you can use the same approach for other classes such as `Rating`, `Customer_Service_Calls`, `Favourited_Route` etc.

Comment: +1 that the current implementation looks sufficient. Just a note of caution, however: it's easy to forget that those ORM calls in the template lead to *actual queries*; you or another dev might later misuse them and cause performance issues. Better IME to give the template only what is needed -- perhaps even transformed into something instead of a `QuerySet` -- and nothing more.

Comment: @spiffyman Thank you. I myself will prefer to set what is required in the context so I can access it as many times and in multiple ways I want to. This was just an alternative suggestion (_since the user asked for it_). On the other hand what would you suggest to transform the objects to (if other than Queryset).

Comment: yes! okay i got it, using `related_name` is so much more useful :) That's great! I feel more confident writing more `DetailView`s from here!

Comment: @AKS Fair. I was offering the caution for the user, not you. :) I'd probably convert the objects into `list`s of `dict`s. This also makes it easy to, for example, serialize it into JSON if you want to work with it in JS on the page. Yes, it's more rigid, but dealing with that is a lot easier than tracking down rogue queries written by someone else. **Edit**: totally depends on your organization, its size, etc. For small/medium projects this is a non-issue.

Comment: Glad that it helped you @bryansis2010.